# Where is dojo.charting library on AOL site?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am testing dojo charting library. I prefer to use the library from AOL web page instead of installing dojo into my computer. I have the following codes:

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.gfx");
    dojo.require("dojox.gfx.move");
    dojo.require("dojo.charting.*");
...
```

I got an error saying "uncaught exception: Could not load cross-domain resources: dojo.charting.*". I guess that my url to dojo library may not have dojo.charting.*. Does any one know what is the correct URL? Is there any way to browse AOL site to find out what libraries available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all like Jarret said: dojox.charting.

Second of all: the "wildcard loading" is obsolete since Dojo 0.4. You cannot use dojo.require("some.package.*") anymore. You have to be explicit about what you need.

The best you can do is to hit [the charting docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/charting) and [tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/) to see how to do it right for your particular needs — you didn't give out any hints of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: you are right on "wildcard loading". When I specified the package, it works.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `dojox.charting`? Instead of `dojo.charting` - notice the lack of x in 'dojo'?

EDIT: AOL's release notes on dojo do not include mention of charting... I suspect you may be on your own here. This link mentions that AOL's 1.2.x release is the same as their 0.4.2 release, where they list their http://dev.aol.com/dojo API inclusions (charting not included). Host charting elsewhere if you need it, by adding a subsequent `<script>` tag, with a different URL for the charting components you need. Or... perhaps AOL is not the appropriate CDN host for you: move your cloud elsewhere :-)

Comment: As an aside, I used to work for AOL... are you sure you wish to use them in this day and age?

Comment: nop. Still not working. I may need to add dojo.js to the URL. How can I add additional library in URL?